# Limit a form post size with Apache / Django

Tags: apache-2.2, django

I have Django running a webapp under Apache2, part of that webapp accepts images posted to a url in Django:

```
http://mysite/upload
```

I would like to find a way to set apache to not allow files over 1MB to be posted - ideally showing a custom error.
I can't find this in the docs, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do this with Apache's [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) method.

> The LimitRequestBody directive allows
>   the user to set a limit on the allowed
>   size of an HTTP request message body
>   within the context in which the
>   directive is given
>
> ...
>
> If, for example, you are permitting
>   file upload to a particular location,
>   and wish to limit the size of the
>   uploaded file to 100K, you might use
>   the following directive:

```
LimitRequestBody 102400
```

Comment: The problem is that browsers don't play well with LimitRequestBody. I've experienced weird problems when using it. EDIT: I've just found the detailed `lecture` on this by Graham Dumpleton: http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg101549.html