# Limit a form post size with Apache / Django - clarification

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi

There is already an answered question on this topic:

[Limit a form post size with Apache / Django](https://serverfault.com/questions/76535/limit-a-form-post-size-with-apache-django)

but I'm not sure what this means: "If, for example, you are permitting file upload to a particular location" (source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) - which location I'm uploading a file to when doing that under Django (WSGI)? Is that directive Apache-wide, or should it be used on some specific folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on where you put the directive.

Use a Location directive to constraint it to a specific URL.

```
<Location /some/suburl>
LimitRequestBody 102400
</Location>
```

If you stick it at VirtualHost level, then applies to all URLs.